# Filter main group members based on subgroup content in reporting services

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting

In reporting services 2008 I have a filter grouping problem.

I want to remove some of the entries in the main group based on certain combinations of subgroup value.

I can make an expression that shows true when a combination is within the group or the inverse, but if I apply this expression to the group it just returns false, hence all the groups are removed.

```
=IIF((Fields!Group2.Value Like "String1") AND (Fields!Group3.Value Like "String2"), 
1, 
IIF(Not(Fields!Group2.Value Like "String1"), 1, 0))
```

If the above is true for all members in group 2 and 3 for the group 1 member it should be shown, if one of the members in the group 2 and 3 returns false the entry in group 1 should be removed.

If I add the above expression to the group 1 filter it always return 1.

The problem is that whether the member in group one consists of 1,1,1,1 or 1,1,0,1  - it always returns 1 on the group one level.

What can I do?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUxED.jpg]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like to you need to check the values one-by-one for a group, and if any one of them fails the test, to produce a false result. It may help you to use an expression like this one:

```
=count("your_group") <= sum(iif(Fields!your_field.Value = yourCondition, 1, 0), "your_group")
```

This takes the total number of rows in your groups, then compares to the sum of the number of times a row meets a condition you set. So if one row fails the test, the expression will return false. One of the important pieces of this expression is the "your_group" part - that is called specifying your scope and is important if you want to reference a different group or level in an expression. More details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255256.aspx). You may have to do a bit of work to make this fit for you.

Comment: Wee - You hint made it. Thank you very much :-) I failed to sum the equation I had put in. I used it without count or sum.